# How to do 3 conditions with if else C#

Tags: c#

I am able to get C# to read 2 of my conditions. I can correctly get the answers: "You blowed 10 whistles" and "Average job blue, your score is 18"

But I cannot get the answer "Superb job red! Your score count is 40", my code will incorrectly say "Average job red, your score is 40".

Please help. *I made this test myself to understand how to do several conditions with if else*

Instructions:

Scenario 1 for player:

1. ask position
2. ask score count
3. ask which team.
4. say "Average job *team*, your score is _"

Scenario 2 for player:

1. ask position
2. ask score count.
3. ask which team.
4. if score count is more than 20, say "Superb job *team*! Your score is _"

Scenario 3 for referee:

1. ask position
2. ask whistle count
3. say "You blowed _ whistles"

Answers:

- position: referee
- total whistles: 10
- "You blowed 10 whistles"

---

- position: player
- score count: 18
- team: blue
- "Average job blue, your score is 18"

---

- position: player
- score count: 40
- team: red
- "Superb job red, your score is 40"

```cs
int totalWhistles = 0, scoreCount = 0;
string position, name, team;

Console.Write("Enter position: ");
position = Console.ReadLine();

if ((position == "Player" || position == "player") && scoreCount < 20)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the score count: ");
        scoreCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter team: ");
        team = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Average job {0}, your score is {1}", team, scoreCount);
    }
    else if ((position == "Player" || position == "player") && scoreCount > 20)
        {
        Console.Write("Enter score count: ");
        scoreCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter team: ");
        team = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Superb job {0}! Your score count is {1}", team, scoreCount);
        }
else if (position == "referee" || position == "Referee")
{
    Console.Write("Enter total whistles: ");
    totalWhistles = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("You blowed {0} whistles", totalWhistles);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You can use `if (position.Equals("Player", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))` to do a case-insensitive comparison in order to determine if what they entered is what you expect. What if they entered `"PLAYER"`? :)

Answer (score 5):

The value of `scoreCount` is not known to your program until the user enters the value. Hence your program will always enter the first branch if the `position` is equal to `"Player"`, because the `scoreCount` is initialized to `0` (`scoreCount < 20` is always true at the time of comparison)

Try reading the value before checking your condition.

```
string position, name, team;

Console.Write("Enter position: ");
position = Console.ReadLine();

if(position.ToLower() == "player")
{
    int scoreCount = 0;

    Console.Write("Enter the score count: ");
    scoreCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Enter team: ");
    team = Console.ReadLine();    

    if(scoreCount < 20)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
else if (position.ToLower() == "referee")
{
    int totalWhistles = 0;
    // ...
}
```

After a bit of refactoring

```cs
public void ProcessPosition()
{
    Console.Write("Enter position: ");
    position = Console.ReadLine();

    if(IsPlayer(position))
    {
        ProcessPlayer();
    }
    else if (IsReferee(position))
    {
        ProcessReferee();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private bool IsPlayer(string position) => position.ToLower() == "player";

private bool IsReferee(string position) => position.ToLower() == "referee";

private ProcessPlayer()
{
    Console.Write("Enter the score count: ");
    var scoreCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Enter team: ");
    var team = Console.ReadLine();   

    var message = GetPlayerMessage(team, scoreCount);
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}

private string GetPlayerMessage(string team, int scoreCount) => scoreCount < 20 
    ? $"Average job {team}, your score is {scoreCount}";
    : $"Superb job {team}! Your score count is {scoreCount}";
```

**Please note:** That I've used the [ternary operator (`?:` operator)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) instead of `if .. else` where I found it useful. Furthermore I've replaced the invocations of `string.Format` with [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), because this allows formatting strings with less clutter. It seems to me, that you are learning C# with outdated tutorials or books. I'd advise you to learn modern C# right away. Have a look at roundups of the latest versions and/or get yourself a recent book (C# 8 at best).

Answer (score 1):

The `scoreCount` value should be outside of If condition not inside the condition block.
     Check the below code:

```
        Console.Write("Enter position: ");
        position = Console.ReadLine();

        // earlier this was inside the if condition.
        Console.Write("Enter the score count: ");
        scoreCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        if ((position == "Player" || position == "player") && scoreCount < 20)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter team: ");
            team = Console.ReadLine();
            //scoreCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); removed from here added on top of if conditon. 
            Console.WriteLine("Average job {0}, your score is {1}", team, scoreCount);
        }
        else if ((position == "Player" || position == "player") && scoreCount > 20)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter team: ");
            team = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Superb job {0}! Your score count is {1}", team, scoreCount);
        }
        else if (position == "referee" || position == "Referee")
        {
            Console.Write("Enter total whistles: ");
            totalWhistles = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("You blowed {0} whistles", totalWhistles);
        }
```

Always your scoreCount is 0 and it will fall under first if condition only.

Comment: @JJLe did you check the answer, does this workout for you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
            int totalWhistles = 0, scoreCount = 0;

            string position = "", team = "";

            Console.Write("Enter position: ");
            position = Console.ReadLine();

            if ((position.ToLower() == "player" ))
            {
                Console.Write("Enter the score count: ");
                scoreCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Enter team: ");
                team = Console.ReadLine();
                if(scoreCount > 20)
                    Console.WriteLine("Superb job {0}! Your score count is {1}", team, scoreCount);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Average job {0}! Your score count is {1}", team, scoreCount);
            }
            else if (position.ToLower() == "referee")
            {
                Console.Write("Enter total whistles: ");
                totalWhistles = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("You blowed {0} whistles", totalWhistles);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```